# How can i get which application launch by user programatically?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, launching

Is there any way to get user launching app information like package name or any information about that application.

i make one service which get all running process and then i just compare with my deserving package name but i want Broadcast intent.

Is there any broadcast intent receiver which revive user launching app info ?

Comment: Take a look [ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED). May be helpful to you

Comment: i want user's launching application every time ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED == when u try to install any pkg but i want any time if user launch X app then i want intent for that

Comment: Ok actually i don't know much more about this.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me, Hope it help you too.

```
IntentFilter addFilter = new IntentFilter();
addFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
addFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL);
addFilter.addDataScheme("package");
registerReceiver(yourReceiverName, addFilter);
```

Comment: :: ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED == when u try to install any pkg and ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL:: A new application package has been installed on the device.

Comment: You can use as per your requirement, for me this both are necessary so i done like that.

Comment: i want any time if user launch X app then i want intent for that

Comment: if i am getting you correct then,  you will get intent data with your receiver (BroadcastReceiver).

Comment: Are you sure about it like every time it will call while that particualar app will launch for example whats app if what app launch 6 time by user then iget 6 time this broad cast dear